# Mongoose: Howto find model with most common items in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have the following database scheme:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');


let keywordSchema = mongoose.Schema({
keyword: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
categories: {
    type: [String],
    default: []
},
});


let phraseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
trainedBy: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
phrase: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
keywords: {
    type: [keywordSchema],
    default: []
  }
});

let Phrase = module.exports = mongoose.model('Phrase', phraseSchema);
```

Given an array of categories (list of strings), I want to query the phrases that has as much common categories as possible, for example:

For the following phrases

```
[{
trainedBy: "me",
text: "I love tomatos",
keywords: [
{
    keyword: "love",
    categories: ["emotions", "feelings", "feeling", "vibe", "heart"]
},
{
    keyword: "tomato",
    categories: ["vegtable", "food", "red"]
}]
},
{
 trainedBy: "me",
 text: "I don't like apples",
 keywords: [
 {
    keyword: "like",
    categories: ["emotions"]
},
{
    keyword: "apples,
    categories: ["fruit"]
  }]
}]
```

and the categories `"emotions", "food"` the phrase that will be returned is `I love tomatos`

any idea how I can go about it?

Comment: what record you want if any of `emotions` or `food` matched?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to you to use aggregation but it will be so complex query because you should unwind and make a conditional choice to which document you want. I don't think the naive ways using `find` will work here. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
db.Phrase.find({
  $and: [
    {
      keywords: {
        $elemMatch: {
          categories: {
            $in: [
              "emotions"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      keywords: {
        $elemMatch: {
          categories: {
            $in: [
              "food"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Here you can add as many conditions in $and depending on your search criteria also it'll only return document if all conditions are met here only returning document having the text "I love tomatos"